# cannot get Firebase data to show in ordered list

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to get my firebase data into an ordered list. i get the data and the ordered list updates when i add more data. but it doesnt show the contents of the data only the numbers.
ii tried appending the child li to the parent ol and it seems to work but the contents just dont show up.
`

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB3lyujRu2g_szT-r0GZF4T12MrzGZJHg8",
    authDomain: "beer-database.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://beer-database-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "beer-database",
    storageBucket: "beer-database.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "237719564948",
    appId: "1:237719564948:web:a16916d042fd96c874ba81",
    measurementId: "G-KHGHBKCJF7"
  };
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Set database variable
var database = firebase.database()

var ref = database.ref('Beers');
ref.on('value',gotData, errData);

function save() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value
  var abv = document.getElementById('abv').value
  var company = document.getElementById('company').value
  var description = document.getElementById('description').value
  var category = document.getElementById('category').value

  database.ref('Beers/' + name).set({
    name : name,
    abv : abv,
    company : company,
    description : description,
    category : category
  })

  alert('Saved')
}

function get() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value

  var name_ref = database.ref('Beers/' + name)
  name_ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val()

    alert(data.name)

  })

}

function update() {
  var username = document.getElementById('name').value
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value

  var updates = {
    email : email,
    password : password
  }

  database.ref('users/' + username).update(updates)

  alert('updated')
}

function remove() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value

  database.ref('Beers/' + name).remove()

  alert('deleted')
}

function gotData(data){

  
    //console.log(data.val());
    var Beers = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(Beers);
    console.log(keys);
    for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){

        var k = keys[i];
        var name = Beers[k].name;
        var abv = Beers[k].abv;
        var company = Beers[k].company;
        var description = Beers[k].description;
        var category = Beers[k].category;
       
       
        // console.log(name,abv,company,description,category)
        var li = document.createElement('li', name + ': ' + company + ': ' + abv + ': ' + description + ': ' + category);
      
        document.getElementById("beerlist").appendChild(li);
    }
}

function errData(err){
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>firebase editable table </title>
</head>


<body>
    <p>
        <div>
        <ol id="beerlist">
        
        </ol>
        </div>
    </p>
  </body>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*emphasized text*`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problems, but `gotData` seems overly complicated. Instead of using a `for` loop and the complex index lookup, consider using Firebase's built-in `forEach` like this:

```
function gotData(snapshot){
    document.getElementById("beerlist").innerHTML = ""; //  clear previous child nodes

    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        const data = child.val()

        var li = document.createElement('li', data.name + ': ' + data.company + ': ' + data.abv + ': ' + data.description + ': ' + data.category);
        document.getElementById("beerlist").appendChild(li);
    }
}
```